# How to call and count variable from one method to another?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, count, call

Hi I would like to get and count all the invalid accounts from the method valSAM using my other method GetSAM.

I've managed to use the count property to get the total number of accounts in the database from the GetSAM method. **(lines 7- 23, GetSAM)** The problem is, I do not know how to replicate that and call/ count the total number of invalid accounts from the valSAM method. **(lines 20- 39, valSAM)**

I have a hunch that I have to somehow call the invalid accounts to the GetSAM method before I am able to call them as well but I do not know how to implement it. Can anyone please advise me on this?

GetSAM method:

```
 //Get SAMAccount
    private static string GetSAM(string ldapAddress, string serviceAccountUserName, string serviceAccountPassword)
    {

        string ldapPath = "LDAP://" + ldapAddress;

        string ldapFilter = "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person))";

        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, serviceAccountUserName, serviceAccountPassword);

        string readOutput;

        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        using (DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry))
        {
            string samAccountName;

            directorySearcher.Filter = ldapFilter;

            directorySearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

            directorySearcher.PageSize = 1000;

            using (SearchResultCollection searchResultCollection = directorySearcher.FindAll())
            {

                foreach (SearchResult result in searchResultCollection)
                {
                    samAccountName = result.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString();

                    valSAM(samAccountName, ldapAddress, serviceAccountUserName, serviceAccountPassword);

                    list.Add(samAccountName);

                }  //end of foreach

                // Count all accounts 
                int totalAccounts = list.Count;

                Console.WriteLine("Found " + totalAccounts + " accounts. Query in " + ldapAddress + " has finished.\n");

                Console.WriteLine("Press [enter] to continue.\n");

                readOutput = Console.ReadLine();

            }//SearchResultCollection will be disposed here
        }
        return readOutput;

    }
```

valSAM method:

```
//Validate SAMAccount
    private static string valSAM(string samAccountName, string ldapAddress, string serviceAccountUserName, string serviceAccountPassword)
    {
        string ldapPath = "LDAP://" + ldapAddress;

        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, serviceAccountUserName, serviceAccountPassword);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();


        //create instance fo the directory searcher
        DirectorySearcher desearch = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);

        //set the search filter
        desearch.Filter = "(&(sAMAccountName=" + samAccountName + ")(objectcategory=user))";

        //find the first instance
        SearchResult results = desearch.FindOne();

        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ldapAddress))
        {

            //if users are present in database
            if (results != null)
            {

                //Check if account is activated
                bool isAccountActived = IsActive(results.GetDirectoryEntry());

                //Check if account is expired or locked
                bool isAccountLocked = IsAccountLockOrExpired(results.GetDirectoryEntry());

                //account is invalid 
                if ((isAccountActived != true) || (isAccountLocked))
                {
                    builder.Append("User account " + samAccountName + " is invalid. ");

                    if ((isAccountActived != true) && (isAccountLocked))
                    {
                        builder.Append("Account is inactive and locked or expired.").Append('\n'); ;
                    } else if (isAccountActived != true)
                    {
                        builder.Append("Account is inactive.").Append('\n'); ;
                    }
                    else if (isAccountLocked)
                    {
                        builder.Append("Account is locked or has expired.").Append('\n'); ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        builder.Append("Unknown reason for status. Contact admin for help.").Append('\n'); ;
                    }

                }

                //account is valid
                if ((isAccountActived) && (isAccountLocked != true))
                {
                    builder.Append("User account " + samAccountName + " is valid.").Append('\n');
                }

            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Nothing found.");

            Console.WriteLine(builder);

        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Updated valSAM:

```
    //Validate SAMAccount
    private static bool valSAM(string samAccountName, string ldapAddress, string serviceAccountUserName, string serviceAccountPassword)
    {
        string ldapPath = "LDAP://" + ldapAddress;

        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, serviceAccountUserName, serviceAccountPassword);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        bool accountValidation = true;

        //create instance fo the directory searcher
        DirectorySearcher desearch = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);

        //set the search filter
        desearch.Filter = "(&(sAMAccountName=" + samAccountName + ")(objectcategory=user))";

        //find the first instance
        SearchResult results = desearch.FindOne();

        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ldapAddress))
        {

            //if users are present in database
            if (results != null)
            {

                //Check if account is activated
                bool isAccountActived = IsActive(results.GetDirectoryEntry());

                //Check if account is expired or locked
                bool isAccountLocked = IsAccountLockOrExpired(results.GetDirectoryEntry());

                accountValidation = ((isAccountActived != true) || (isAccountLocked));

                //account is invalid 
                if (accountValidation)
                {
                    builder.Append("User account " + samAccountName + " is invalid. ");

                    if ((isAccountActived != true) && (isAccountLocked))
                    {
                        builder.Append("Account is inactive and locked or expired.").Append('\n'); ;
                    } else if (isAccountActived != true)
                    {
                        builder.Append("Account is inactive.").Append('\n'); ;
                    }
                    else if (isAccountLocked)
                    {
                        builder.Append("Account is locked or has expired.").Append('\n'); ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        builder.Append("Unknown reason for status. Contact admin for help.").Append('\n'); ;
                    }

                    return false;

                }

                //account is valid
                if ((isAccountActived) && (isAccountLocked != true))
                {
                    builder.Append("User account " + samAccountName + " is valid.").Append('\n');

                    return true;
                }

            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Nothing found.");

            Console.WriteLine(builder);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }//end of using
        return accountValidation;
    }
```

Thanks a million :)

Update: Now I have a new problem after updating my valSAM- I am unable to print out the accounts when I return the boolean accountValidation instead of builder.ToString().

Comment: When you call `valSAM`, you should return a bool instead of string, and based on that declare a variable that should be incremented if the value returned is false (i.e when the account is invalid).

Comment: Never mind, solved it. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the call before you do Console.WriteLine, do something like this:

```
private static bool valSAM(string samAccountName, string ldapAddress, string serviceAccountUserName, string serviceAccountPassword)
    {
        string ldapPath = "LDAP://" + ldapAddress;

        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, serviceAccountUserName, serviceAccountPassword);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        bool accountValidation = true;

        //create instance fo the directory searcher
        DirectorySearcher desearch = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);

        //set the search filter
        desearch.Filter = "(&(sAMAccountName=" + samAccountName + ")(objectcategory=user))";

        //find the first instance
        SearchResult results = desearch.FindOne();

        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ldapAddress))
        {

            //if users are present in database
            if (results != null)
            {

                //Check if account is activated
                bool isAccountActived = IsActive(results.GetDirectoryEntry());

                //Check if account is expired or locked
                bool isAccountLocked = IsAccountLockOrExpired(results.GetDirectoryEntry());

                accountValidation = ((isAccountActived != true) || (isAccountLocked));

                //account is invalid 
                if (accountValidation)
                {
                    builder.Append("User account " + samAccountName + " is invalid. ");

                    if ((isAccountActived != true) && (isAccountLocked))
                    {
                        builder.Append("Account is inactive and locked or expired.").Append('\n'); ;
                    } else if (isAccountActived != true)
                    {
                        builder.Append("Account is inactive.").Append('\n'); ;
                    }
                    else if (isAccountLocked)
                    {
                        builder.Append("Account is locked or has expired.").Append('\n'); ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        builder.Append("Unknown reason for status. Contact admin for help.").Append('\n'); ;
                    }

                    accountValidation = false;

                }

                //account is valid
                if ((isAccountActived) && (isAccountLocked != true))
                {
                    builder.Append("User account " + samAccountName + " is valid.").Append('\n');

                    accountValidation = true;
                }

            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Nothing found.");

            Console.WriteLine(builder);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }//end of using
        return accountValidation;
    }
```

So now, you can assign the value and have one return point and can also print the names. As for keeping track of counts in main function you can place valSAM call in

```
if(valSAM(samAccountName, ldapAddress, serviceAccountUserName, serviceAccountPassword))
{
  invalidAccountCount++;
}
```

And needless to say, you have to initialize invalidAccountCount outside the loop.